# Cant seem to get this plugin to respond to my termination of the setTimeout. Any help?

Tags: jquery-plugins

The test can be found here. I would like to be able to pass my plugin a new option string of 'false' and have my timer stop. http://www.jsfiddle.net/j78nk/2/

Comment: You need to post a lot more context and a lot more information. And don't expect us to go to external websites. Post your question here.

Answer (score -1):

There is no element with the class `gallery2` on that page, so pressing the button won't do anything.

Also, you are not checking the set options, only the defaults.  And you `return` right away, before you do anything:

```
            if (!defaults.running) {
                return;
                console.log('timer is inactive');
            }
```

That code needs to be:

```
            if (!options.running) {
                console.log('timer is inactive');
                return;
            }
```